# How to execute unix commands sequentilly on two different users on same server with single shell script?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

**Please find sample code**

`Sample test.ksh :`

Below is the code  that I have used to run on two users, however when  run the script it ust executes the first command and i.e sx su command and stops executing further

```
#!/bin/ksh 

sx su - user1    
cat testfile.txt    
exit  

sx su - user2    
cd /bin    
ls -lrta
```

Comment: Please use right formatting to make your question more clear. Did you get any error when you execute this code?

Comment: I didn't get any error, the script just stopped executing further after switching to user 1

Comment: you realized that `exit` means **exit**? Code is working as written. You'll have to either remove the call to `exit` or make it conditional, ie `if [ $? != 0 ] ; then exit ; fi` (or similar). Good luck.

Comment: Hello @shelter, for me to switch to user 2 from user 1, I have to come out of user 1. There is no access granted for user1 to su to user 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like (as root!)

```
#!/bin/ksh 

su - user1 -c "cat testfile.txt"    
su - user2 -c "cd /bin; ls -lrta"
```

Comment: Hi romea, Thanks mate but I don't have root access.